# why React Router not rendering dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hi i am having trouble in mapping url in react.i am complete new to react js.i am trying to render a component into my App js,when i render it as component like  things goes well but when i try to render it as a Route i am getting this error i tried some available solution form stackoverflow like importing it as 'react-route-dom',Routes instead of Router but still unable to fix this bug.please guide me to fix this bug

```
enter code here
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Route,
    }   from "react-router-dom";

import './App.css';
import Header from './componnents/Header'
import NotesPage from './Pages/NotesPage'
import NotePage from './Pages/NotePage'
function App() {
     return (
             <div className="App">
                   <Header />
                   <Router>
                           <Route exact path="/" component={NotesPage} />
                   </Router>
            </div>);}
            export default App;
```

this is my error:

```
   index.tsx:19 
   Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never 
    rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.
at invariant (index.tsx:19:1)
at Route (index.tsx:230:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
invariant @ index.tsx:19
Route @ index.tsx:230
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:14985
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17811
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19049
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23964
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22776
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22293
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
./src/index.js @ index.js:6
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
react-dom.development.js:20085 
    
   The above error occurred in the <Route> component:

at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35654:11)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35669:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35149:5)
at div
at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:20085
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:20118
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:12318
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12339
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:20736
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23426
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23151
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22990
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22329
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
./src/index.js @ index.js:6
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
index.tsx:19 
    
   Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never 
 rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.
at invariant (index.tsx:19:1)
at Route (index.tsx:230:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
invariant @ index.tsx:19
Route @ index.tsx:230
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:14985
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17811
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19049
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23964
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22776
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22293
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
./src/index.js @ index.js:6
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
```

Answer (score 3):

From the error message, i understand that you use react-router-dom v6. With v6 some components has changed. You should use `<Route />` component inside of `<Routes />` and use `element` instead of `component` as prop.

```
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route exact={true} path="/" element={<NotesPage />} />
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2):

As your error message says

> A `<Route>` is only ever to be used as the child of `<Routes>` element, never
> rendered directly. Please wrap your `<Route>` in a `<Routes>`.

You need to wrap the `Route` with `Routes`

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" component={NotesPage} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

See more of React Router :
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Answer (score 2):

First, when you encounter a question, you should always look for the answers in the official website of `react-router` or its `github issues` to find the closest answers or the same ones, and don't forget to check the library version cause there would be difference between previous and current version.

As mentioned above, `Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>` is exactly the problem lies, so the quickest solution is as following:

```
//Remember to import {Routes} from 'react-router-dom' first
 <Router>
   <Routes>
     <Route exact path="/" component={NotesPage} />
   </Routes>
 </Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom";
```

You just need to add the `<Routes></Routes>`

The `<Router>` is component from react-router-dom v5 as you see you have installed react-router-dom v6 and need all the `<Route>` component to wrapped with `<Routes>` too.

You can check the docs also for that

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Your Final result will be like this :

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" component={NotesPage} />
  </Routes>
<Router>
```